# Create dictionary from 2 columns of Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
'ID': ['1', '4', '4', '3', '3', '3'], 
'club': ['arts', 'math', 'theatre', 'poetry', 'dance', 'cricket']
})
```

Note: Both the columns of the data frame can have repeated values.

I want to create a dictionary of dictionaries for every rank with its unique club names.
It should look like this:

```
{
{'1':'arts'}, {'4':'math','theatre'}, {'3':'poetry','dance','cricket'}
}
```

Kindly help me with this

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Can you add a draft of your code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `groupby()` and then `to_dict()`:

```
grouped = df.groupby("ID")["club"].apply(set)
print(grouped)
> ID
   1                      {arts}
   3    {cricket, poetry, dance}
   4             {math, theatre}

grouped_dict = grouped.to_dict()
print(grouped_dict)
> {'1': {'arts'}, '3': {'cricket', 'poetry', 'dance'}, '4': {'math', 'theatre'}}
```

##### Edit:

Changed to `.apply(set)` to get sets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(set)
for k,v in zip(df['ID'], df['club']):
    d[k].add(v)
dict(d)
```

output:

```
{'1': {'arts'}, '4': {'math', 'theatre'}, '3': {'cricket', 'dance', 'poetry'}}
```

or for a format similar to the provided output:

```
[{k:v} for k,v in d.items()]
```

output:

```
[{'1': {'arts'}},
 {'4': {'math', 'theatre'}},
 {'3': {'cricket', 'dance', 'poetry'}}]
```